# Dynamic table using Bootstrap3 is not working properly.

Tags: php, mysql, html

Table sorting and searching text filed is not working properly using bootstrap 3. I am basically developing a query builder and making a dynamic table of my data but table sorting and searching is not working properly. Data display accurately but the table sort and search text box do not display data.

```
<?php
     ini_set( "display_errors", 0);
     include "include.php";
     include "connect_to_mysql.php";
     $table='Genomics_data_ncbi';
     $display = array();
     $qu_mul="";
     ?>           
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>TODO supply a title</title>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <script type="text/javascript">
                function formValidation(form)
                {
                var ccc = document.getElementById("first_box").value;
                if(ccc == "") {
                alert("Please enter a keyword !!!");
                return false;
                }
                }
                var intTextBox=0;

                //FUNCTION TO ADD TEXT BOX ELEMENT
                function addElement()
                {
                intTextBox = intTextBox + 1;
                var contentID = document.getElementById("content");
                var newTBDiv = document.createElement("div");
                newTBDiv.setAttribute("id","strText"+intTextBox);
                newTBDiv.innerHTML = "<select name='op[]'><option value='and'>AND</option> <option value='or'>OR</option> </select><select name='fieldsi[]'><option value='all'>All Fields</option><option value='' align='center' style='background-color: #FFCCCC'>Genome Information</option><option value='Gene_id'>Gene_id</option><option value='Gene_name'>Gene_name</option><option value='Gene_product'>Gene_product</option><option value='Function_of_proteins'>Function_of_proteins</option><option value='Protein_id'>Protein_id</option><option value='Localization_of_proteins'>Localization_of_proteins</option><option value='Strain_id'>Strain_id</option></select><select name='fieldsi_op[]'><option value='like'>LIKE</option><option value='not like'>Not LIKE</option><option value='equal'>Equal to</option><option value='not_equal'>Not equal to</option><option value='='> = </option><option value='!='> != </option><option value='<='> <= </option><option value='>='> >= </option><option value='<'> < </option><option value='>'> > </option></select> <input type='text' id='" + intTextBox + "' name='keyword[]'>";
                contentID.appendChild(newTBDiv);
                }
                //FUNCTION TO REMOVE TEXT BOX ELEMENT
                function removeElement()
                {
                if(intTextBox != 0)
                {
                var contentID = document.getElementById("content");
                contentID.removeChild(document.getElementById("strText"+intTextBox));
                intTextBox = intTextBox-1;
                }
                }
                </script>
    <!--<staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
    </staticContent>
        <p>
       <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-default">
          <span class = "glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot"></span>
       </button>
            <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-default">
          <span class = "glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf"></span>
       </button>
            <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-default">
          <span class = "glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff"></span>
       </button>
            <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-default">
          <span class = "glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg"></span>
       </button>
        <link href="tablesort/css/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="tablesort/css/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="tablesort/css/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="tablesort/css/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg" rel="stylesheet">-->

        <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="tablesort/js/jquery-3.3.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="tablesort/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="tablesort/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="tablesort/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="tablesort/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>


        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable();
    } );
        </script>
        </head>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <font color="#3d4983" face="Verdana" size="3"><b>Query Builder</b></font>
                <br>
                <p align='justify'>Users may build complex queries using the logical operators 'AND' and 'OR'. Each sub-query can be built using other operators such as LIKE, NOT LIKE, EQUAL and NOT EQUAL TO while dealing with strings like 
                words or letters and =, !=, <=, >=, < and > while dealing with numerical values. The Query builder aids to the flexibility of performing search on a number of fields simultaneously.</p>
                <br>
                <form name='form1' action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method='post' onsubmit="return formValidation(this);">
                <select name='fieldsi[]'>
                <option value='all'>All Fields</option>
                <option value='' style="background-color: #FFCCCC">Gene Information</option>
                <option value='Gene_id'>Gene id</option>
                <option value='Gene_name'>Locus tag</option>
                <option value='Gene_product'> Gene product</option>
                <option value='Function_of_proteins'> Protein function</option>
                <option value='Protein_id'> Protein ID</option>
                <option value='Localization_of_proteins'> Localization of protein</option>
                <option value='Strain_id'> Strain ID</option>
                </select>
                <select name='fieldsi_op[]'>
                <option value='like'>LIKE</option>
                <option value='not like'>Not LIKE</option>
                <option value='equal'>Equal to</option>
                <option value='not_equal'>Not equal to</option>
                <option value='='> = </option>
                <option value='!='> != </option>
                <option value='<='> <= </option>
                <option value='>='> >= </option>
                <option value='<'> < </option>
                <option value='>'> > </option>
                </select> 
                <input type='text' name='keyword[]' id='first_box'>
                <input type="button" onclick="addElement()" value="+">&nbsp;<input type="button" onclick="removeElement()" value="-">
                <div id="content" ></div>
                <br>
                <input type='submit' value='Search'>
                </form>
                <br>
                <br>
                <body>

                <?php
                $dbServerName = "abc";
                $dbUsername = "abc";
                $dbPassword = "abc";
                $dbName = "abc";
                // create connection
                $conn = new mysqli($dbServerName, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
                // check connection
                if ($conn->connect_error) {
                    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                }
                $sql = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table";
                if(isset($_POST['keyword'])){
                $key = $_POST['keyword'];
                $op = $_POST['op'];
                $field = $_POST['fieldsi'];
                $field_op = $_POST['fieldsi_op'];
                for($i=0;$i<count($key);$i++){
                    $keyw = $key[$i];
                    $field_val = $field[$i];
                $field_op_val = $field_op[$i];
                if($i>0){
                $j = $i-1;
                $operate = $op[$j];
                if($operate != 'not'){
                if($field_val == 'all'){
                $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                $result1 = mysqli_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table");
                echo "$result1";
                if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
                {
                $i=0;
                  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
                   {
                if($i==0)
                {
                $fi_name = $row[0];
                $display["$fi_name"] = 0;
                $qu_mul = $qu_mul.' '.$operate.' '."$fi_name $field_op_val '%$keyw%'";
                }
                else
                {
                $fi_name = $row[0];
                $display["$fi_name"] = 0;
                $qu_mul.=" or "."$fi_name $field_op_val '%$keyw%'";
                }
                $i++;
                }
                }
                }
                else{
                $display["$field_val"] = 0;
                if(!preg_match('/[like]/i', $field_op_val)){
                $qu_mul = $qu_mul.' '.$operate.' '."$field_val $field_op_val $keyw";
                }
                else if(preg_match('/equal/i', $field_op_val)){
                $qu_mul = $qu_mul.' '.$operate.' '."$field_val ='$keyw'";
                }
                else if(preg_match('/not_equal/i', $field_op_val)){
                $qu_mul = $qu_mul.' '.$operate.' '."$field_val !='$keyw'";
                }
                else{
                $qu_mul = $qu_mul.' '.$operate.' '."$field_val $field_op_val '%$keyw%'";

                }

                }
                }

                else{
                $qu_mul = $qu_mul.' '."and $field_val not like '%$keyw%'";

                }

                }
                else{
                if($field_val == 'all'){
                $result = mysqli_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table");

                if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
                {
                $i=0;
                  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                   {
                if($i==0)
                {
                $fi_name = $row[0];
                $display["$fi_name"] = 0;
                if(!preg_match('/[like]/i', $field_op_val)){
                    $qu = "$fi_name $field_op_val $keyw";
                }
                else if(preg_match('/equal/i', $field_op_val)){
                    $qu = "$fi_name ='$keyw'";
                }
                else if(preg_match('/not_equal/i', $field_op_val)){
                    $qu = "$fi_name !='$keyw'";
                }
                else{
                    $qu = "$fi_name $field_op_val '%$keyw%'";

                }

                }
                else
                {
                $fi_name = $row[0];
                $display["$fi_name"] = 0;
                if(!preg_match('/[like]/i', $field_op_val)){
                $qu.=" or "."$fi_name $field_op_val $keyw";
                }
                else if(preg_match('/equal/i', $field_op_val)){
                $qu.=" or "."$fi_name ='$keyw'";
                }
                else if(preg_match('/not_equal/i', $field_op_val)){
                $qu.=" or "."$fi_name !='$keyw'";
                }
                else{
                $qu.=" or "."$fi_name $field_op_val '%$keyw%'";
                }

                }
                $i++;
                }
                }
                }
                else{
                    $display["$field_val"] = 0;
                if(!preg_match('/[like]/i', $field_op_val)){
                $qu = "$field_val $field_op_val $keyw";
                }
                else if(preg_match('/equal/i', $field_op_val)){
                $qu = "$field_val ='$keyw'";
                }
                else if(preg_match('/not_equal/i', $field_op_val)){
                $qu = "$field_val !='$keyw'";
                }
                else{
                $qu = "$field_val $field_op_val '%$keyw%'";

                }

                }

                }

                }
                $dis="";
                $display["Gene_id"] = 0;
                #echo "$display";
                $display["Gene_name"] = 0;
                $display["Gene_product"] = 0;
                $display["Function_of_proteins"] = 0;
                $display["Protein_id"] = 0;
                #$display["Protein_sequence"] = 0;
                #$display["Nucleotide_sequence"] = 0;
                $display["Protein_length"] = 0;
                $display["Localization_of_proteins"] = 0;
                $display["Strain_id"] = 0;
                $display["Source"] = 0;
                foreach($display as $key => $value){
                $dis = "$dis"."$key,";
                #echo "$dis";

                }
                $dis = preg_replace("/,$/",'',$dis);
                $qu_pre = "select $dis from $table where ";
                $sql = "$qu_pre"."$qu"."$qu_mul";
                $res = $conn->query("$sql") or die($conn->error);
                #echo"<table border=1>";
                $res_no = mysqli_num_rows($res);
                if($res_no == 0){
                 "<font color='brown' size='4'><b>No Record Found in CRAB-DB coressponding to your keyword !!!</b></font><br><br><input type='button' value='Go Back' onClick='history.go(-1)'><br><br><br>";
                }
                else{
                $tot_res = mysqli_num_rows($res);
                echo "Total number of records = $tot_res";

                                echo '<br>';
        #<!-- back working properly-->
                    echo "<input type='button' onClick='history.go(-1)' value='Back'><br><br>"; 
                    echo '<div style="padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;">'; 
                                            $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                        #echo "<table cellspacing=\"1\" class=\"tablesorter\">";
                        #echo "<thead><tr>";

                if (mysqli_num_rows($query)){

                    $headerRow = true;
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
                        if ($headerRow){
                            $headerRow = false;




    echo '<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">';
            echo "<thead>";
                echo "<tr>";
                    foreach (array_keys($row) as $header)
                  {


                                echo "<th align = left>$header</a></th>";

                            }


                echo "</tr>";
            echo "</thead>";
             }
                        echo '<tbody>';
            #echo "<tbody>";
                echo "<tr>";
                    #echo "<td>";
                foreach ($row as $value){
                            echo "<td>$value</td>";
                        }
                        echo "</td>";

                echo "</tr>";
                 #echo '</tr>';
                        echo '</tbody>';

                    }

                }




                }


                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){

                    for($i=0;$i<mysqli_num_fields($res);$i++){

                            $f_name = mysqli_field_name($res, $i);
                             $f_val = $row[$f_name];
                            if($f_name == 'Gene_name'){
                                print"<td>$f_val</td>";
                                print "<td><a href='#####.php?Gene_name=$f_val&type=Gene_name' title='Click to See Details' style='text-decoration: none;'>$f_val</a></td>";
                            }
                            else if($f_name == 'Gene_id'){
                            $c_id = $row['Gene_name'];
                            $res_pub = mysqli_query("select * from $table where Gene_name='$c_id'");

                            }
                            print "</th>";
                        }

                }
                }
                echo "</table>";



                  echo "<tfoot>";
                echo "<tr>";
                    foreach (array_keys($row) as $header)
                  {


                                echo "<th align = left>$header</a></th>";

                            }


                echo "</tr>";

        echo "</table>";
        echo "</body>";
    echo "</html>";
```

Comment: Your files aren't being found, therefore your code fails. Make sure the `src` property has the correct url. Try and access each in a separate tab.

Answer (score 0):

Your code uses relative links. Don't do that. Use Absolute links!

```
<script src="jquery-3.3.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Depending which folder this script is in, it will look from there, and not the site root.

However, changing it to

```
<script src="/path/to/jquery-3.3.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Will load it from the site root all the time! In the example I put `/path/to/jquery.js`, if your index.php is in the public folder, then i usually put js in a js folder, so the link would be `/js/jquery-3.3.1.js`

Comment: I have done the same but it is not working. <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="tablesort/js/jquery-3.3.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="tablesort/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="tablesort/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="tablesort/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="tablesort/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

Comment: Has anybody faced server side scripting problem. I think the bootstrap 3 data tables are not working due to this problem and I am unable to solve it.

Comment: fix your links to start with slash, update your question, don't paste loads of code in a comment, it's unreadable